# reactjs callback got fired before it is called

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I try to chain multiple axios requests with `axios.all()`, and pass a callback to the function where I do the calls. After I try to call the `callback` after i spreaded the results with `axios.spread()`, but the second `then()` with the `callback` gets fired before I received the data, so I can't dispatch the right data to the store.

Here is the action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {SET_UPDATE_SCHEDULES} from './types';

let requestData;

const getAttributes = (updateSchedules, callback) => {
  let promises = [];
  updateSchedules.map((updateSchedule) => {
    promises.push(axios.get(updateSchedule.status.href, requestData).then(res => updateSchedule.statusName = res.data.name));

    promises.push(axios.get(updateSchedule.edge_device.href, requestData).then( res => updateSchedule.edgeDeviceName = res.data.serial_number))
  })


  axios.all(promises)
  .then(axios.spread(function(...promises){
    console.log("requests")
    promises.map((promise) => console.log(promise))
  }))
  .then(callback(updateSchedules)) //Here it gets fired before I receive the data
}

export const getUpdateSchedules = (selectedDB,userData) => dispatch =>{

  requestData = userData;

  axios.get(selectedDB+'somelink/id', requestData)
  .then(res => getAttributes(res.data.update_schedules,function(updateSchedules){
    console.log("update")
  }
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets fired immediately because you are invoking it immediately. Try like this:

```
.then( () => callback( updateSchedules ) );
```

.then method takes two callback functions as arguments. One for success one fore failure.

```js
const foo = () =>
  new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => resolve( "success"))
    .then(
          success => console.log( success ),
          failure => console.log( failure )
    );

foo();
```

For example in the above code, our promise console logs success or failure depending on the promises situation. We can omit the callback and use console.log (as our function) if we don't need the argument explicitly.

```js
const foo = () =>
  new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => resolve( "success"))
    .then( console.log, console.log );

foo();
```

This is the same as before. But, again console.log does not immediately fired here since we are not invoking it, just using it with the reference.

For your situation, if you would not need an argument you could use your function as in this example above:

```js
const foo = ( customFunction ) => {
  new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => resolve( "success"))
    .then( console.log, console.log )
    .then( customFunction );
}

const customFunction = () => console.log( "custom message" );

foo( customFunction );
```

Here, we are omitting our success callback function but use our customFunction as reference, does not invoke it. It works. But if we need an argument and use it without a callback it does not work and fires immediately since we are actually invoking it:

```js
const foo = ( customFunction ) => {
  new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => resolve( "success"))
    .then( console.log, console.log )
    .then( customFunction( "custom message") );
}

const customFunction = ( message ) => console.log( message );

foo( customFunction );
```

So, we use success callback function to fix this:

```js
const foo = ( customFunction ) => {
  new Promise( ( resolve, reject) => resolve( "success"))
    .then( console.log, console.log )
    .then( () => customFunction( "custom message") );
}

const customFunction = ( message ) => console.log( message );

foo( customFunction );
```

Comment: You are welcome. I've widen my answer to explain what is going on behind the `.then` method.